# Why email sent has no subject?

Tags: python, email

The subject doesn't send with mails and it is my first time to use python what should I do?
Do I need to add more attachments?
Can someone figure out what is wrong in this code? I think `mailServer` is not working out as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders
import os

gmail_user = "mail@jj.com"
gmail_pwd = "password"

def mail(to, subject, text):
   msg = MIMEMultipart()

   msg['From'] = gmail_user
   msg['To'] = to
   msg['Subject'] = subject

   msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

   mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.starttls()
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
   mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
   mailServer.close()


f = open("try1.txt","r")
for line in f:
    mail(line, "test", "bla bla bla bla balb")
```

Comment: Ahmed, you need to clarify your question - it is not clear what you re trying to achieve. Please be patient and explain, it helps others to be able to help you more efficiently.

Comment: @user702846: Question seems fairly clear to me...